# Android Emulator throws UnknownHostException

Tags: android, permissions, emulation

i'm just trying to code an uploader-app.
I'm using NetBeans and its Android Addon.

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to the manifest!

Also i turned off my firewall for testing, if the `java.net.UnknownHostException` will throw.

But in my App it will be thrown in any case!
The browser on `www.google.de` is running perfectly. But not on my App.

Debugging on a real device is not possible in this case.

Comment: are you able to open same link on native web browser .. as I want to confirm your emulator network working fine ?

Comment: Works on browser, not on app.

Comment: Aren't you by any chance trying to access a service running on your local development box? In context of emulator, "localhost" is the emulator itself, not your development system...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

Comment: Are you giving correct URL? Copy-paste the same URL into browser and check